# Show data in two new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table where I store geological samples with their value in gold and silver.

```
CREATE TABLE samples
(
     id INT, 
     element VARCHAR (10), 
     value INT, 
);

INSERT INTO samples VALUES (1, 'gold', 100);
INSERT INTO samples VALUES (1, 'silver', 150);
INSERT INTO samples VALUES (2, 'gold', 200);
INSERT INTO samples VALUES (2, 'silver', 300);
```

| id | element | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | gold | 100 |
| 1 | silver | 150 |
| 2 | gold | 200 |
| 2 | silver | 300 |

I need a query to obtain the results of gold and silver in columns, like this. "gold" and "silver" are static values, so the query does not need to dynamically consider another type of item.

| id | gold | silver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 150 |
| 2 | 200 | 300 |

I would like to place a try, but I just don't know how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when element = 'gold' then value end) as gold,
       sum(case when element = 'silver' then value end) as silver
from samples s
group by id;
```